# AWS RDS IP static or dynamic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance with a URL that was provided by Amazon. (This URL has an IP that's associated with (of course)).

To make connecting to the DB easier I made a redirect from my domain like this: "**db.myDomain.com**" to the IP of the DB Instance.

For a week it all worked fine, but then, suddenly, it stopped working. After searching for a few hours, I have realized that the IP I was redirecting to was not the same as the IP of the instance.

This made me think that maybe the IPs on RDS are dynamic and the only way to access the DB is with the URL provided by Amazon.

Is this correct? If so, is there away to redirect from one URL to another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your observation about the dynamic nature of the IPs for RDS is correct and it is the anticipated behaviour of the Service. Always use the URL provided for RDS instance to access it RDS instance(s).

For most of the use cases, you don't to do a redirect to access; as the DNS name would go inside a config file / connection string. If you still need a friendly name - you may use the Route53 to create an alias. Here is a documentation link from AWS to accomplish that [ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-rds-db.html ] - it is easier & convenient.

Comment: Hi @Vijay, I'm kind of new to AWS and just found out this little information regarding RDS's dynamic IP. May I ask do they reboot the network on each IP change? say I have a web server connecting it using connection pool, do they drop my connection when the IP changes?

Comment: I am unsure of what happens behind the scenes about the IP reset issue. For your problem at hand if you use the URL - DNS name of the RDS - you shouldn't face any problem. Do not dig for for the IP and use; rather use the URL directly.

Comment: These behavior could affect you if you use Foreign Tables in Postgres as you will need to authorize the public IPs of your own RDS in the Security Group.

You can also modify the value `rds.custom_dns_resolution` to `1` to force your RDS instance to use your default VPC DNS (as by default an RDS public DB will use an external DNS from the Internet).

Also, I found great help in this article. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=295110

Answer (score 4):

For RDS instance, the DNS name is not changed, but IP address will be changed in some case, especially when you enable `Multi-AZ` (multiple available zone), the RDS instance will be switched to other available zone with different IP address when AWS found any fails in it.

So in your application, you can't fix the IP address for your database accessing, always set DNS (domain name) to access your database.